# EXC_BAD_ACCESS only on device when allocating an object

Tags: ios

I am getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS error at the line

```
GADRequest *request = [[GADRequest alloc] init];
```

I don't have source code of GADRequest as its from Google AdMob SDK.
The stack trace is below.
Its happening only on device and not on simulator.

```
#0  0x34a80462 in objc_msgSend ()
#1  0x0017d9dc in +[GADRequest alloc] (self=<value temporarily unavailable, due to optimizations>, _cmd=<value temporarily unavailable, due to optimizations>) at /Users/mikeying/work/ios_sdk_git/googlemac/iPhone/GoogleAds/NextGen/Request/GADRequest.m:48
#2  0x0006e728 in -[AdWhirlAdapterGoogleAdMobAds getAd] (self=0x5511c0, _cmd=0x225209) at /Users/xxx/yyy/libs/AdWhirl/adapters/AdWhirlAdapterGoogleAdMobAds.m:68
#3  0x0007b4f6 in -[AdWhirlView makeAdRequest:] (self=0x5538f0, _cmd=0x22691c, isFirstRequest=1 '\001') at /Users/xxx/yyy/libs/AdWhirl/internal/AdWhirlView.m:370
#4  0x0007ac5c in -[AdWhirlView buildPrioritizedAdNetCfgsAndMakeRequest] (self=0x5538f0, _cmd=0x226965) at /Users/xxx/yyy/libs/AdWhirl/internal/AdWhirlView.m:235
#5  0x35818bbe in -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:] ()
```

Comment: It kinda looks like GADRequest is supplying its own `alloc` method, which is a tricky thing to do.  Is this an ARC environment?  Probably supplying your own `alloc` in ARC is verboten.

Comment: I don't think they are supplying their own alloc. I think the issue might be in some static intializer which is triggered when object is created. But the problem is how to identify it without source code

Comment: The error is out of `alloc`.  You never see an error out of `alloc`.  They're doing something strange.  And, again, is this an ARC environment?

Comment: Automatic Reference Counting.  It comes with iOS 5, and you will need to learn about it if you keep working with iOS.

Answer (score 0):

The program receives the EXC_BAD_ACCESS signal when a message is sent to an object that has been deallocated. With the environment variable NSZombieEnabled set to YES, objects are never deallocated, but instead kept in memory as zombie objects. When a message is sent to a zombie object, execution stops at the line that would normally cause the EXC_BAD_ACCESS signal.

In Xcode 4.2, you could set environment variables by editing scheme, select the “Run XYZ.app” stage in the left panel, then select the “Arguments” tab on the right.

It’s important that you disable NSZombieEnabled once you’re done, or your application would use a tremendous amount of memory and eventually would crash.